# Asynchronous Return Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, setinterval, synchronous

Is there a way to make a POST request in Javascript/jQuery and use that variable as a `setTimeout` time?

```
$.post('file.php', { action: "gettimeout"}, 
function(time){
    return time;
});
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, time);
```

is what I am trying to do.

I am currently able to do but I am doing it synchronously.

```
var time = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'file.php',
    data: {action: "gettimeout"},
    async: false
});
return Number(time.responseText);
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, time);
```

Comment: You should use callbacks. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/1056133

Answer (score 1):

Just put your call to `setInterval` (or `setTimeout`) inside the Ajax callback function:

```
$.post('file.php', { action: "gettimeout"}, function(time){
    setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, time);
});
```

NB: there is no sense in returning a value in the Ajax callback function. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).